# Checking if a number is a Happy Number or not Java

Tags: java

I'm currently doing a challenge on a website to do with checking if a number is a [Happy Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) or not. The program is to read in a file with a list of numbers, one on each line and determine if it is a happy number. I'm having some trouble with implementing the check to see if the number is happy or not.

The happy part is fairly straight forward, if it gets to 1 it is a happy number. The problem occurs for me if the number is not happy it will never get to 1 and will stay in an infinite loop so I'm not sure on how to track that successfully

Here is the code:

```
package com.jconnolly.codeeval;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HappyNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HappyNumbers hn = new HappyNumbers();
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader br;
    String[] numbers;
    try {
        // Read in file
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        // Store each line as a string in an array
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            numbers = line.split("\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if(hn.isHappy(numbers[i])) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(0);
                }
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

// Separates digits, squares them and adds them together
public boolean isHappy(String str) {

    int sum = 0;
    // Holds numbers after they are squared and added together
    ArrayList<Integer> happy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // Separates the digits to be squared
    while((sum != 1) && !happy.contains(sum)) {

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            Character c = new Character(str.charAt(i));
            String character = c.toString();
            int digit = Integer.parseInt(character);
            sum += (digit * digit);
        }
        happy.add(sum);
    }
    happy.clear();
    return sum == 1;
}
```

Any advice on a better implementation or correction would be greatly appreciated. It does give results but they are incorrect. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could this be done using recursion?

Comment: @asaini007 Detecting a cycle greater than 2 would be hard with recursion.

Comment: Is there any sort of rounding that occurs? like if you get a 7 somewhere and you have to take sqrt(7) which would obviously not equal a whole number.

Comment: I'm confused why you have both a while loop and a for loop. Is this what you mean to do:

        for(int i = 0; (sum != 1) && !happy.contains(sum)&&i < str.length(); i++) {

Comment: @asaini007 I tried using recursion but had huge stackoverflow problems so was hoping there was an easier solution. Alex Johnson sqrt doesn't get used in the problem it uses the squares of the individual digits in the number and adds them together

Comment: Every number, happy or sad, is guaranteed to settle under 273. At that point, you must converge in less than `x` iterations or never converge at all. My upper bound for `x` is 273, because if you iterated under 273 more than 273 times you would have to use the same number twice.

Comment: @Schonge is my recursive solution similar to the one you tried?

Comment: @woodlumhoodlum the for loop is just to iterate through each digit in the number to convert it from a string to a character to a number in order to square the digits and get the sum of those squares. The for loop is then suppose to re enter the next number as long as it passes the tests which is where I think the problem may be. I don't think I have the numbers passing back in correctly.

Comment: @asaini007 not quite :-) however seen your solution suggests that perhaps I should convert the strings from the file to integers instead of messing with strings and characters which also makes your solution look alot more understandable and less complex than what mine certainly looked. I will try that out thank you

Comment: The Wikipedia page that you linked to actually gives you a really easy way to tell if you're in an infinite loop.  (However, taking advantage of it might be considered cheating in some sense...)

Comment: @JoshM: A code review is good for code which the author believes to be as good as possible. The site http://codereview.stackexchange.com is currently good for nothing, but this is a different story. **The fact that the OP posted some code is no reason for marking it off-topic.** You could close most of the question here as belonging to CR because of this.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of to test for "never reaches 1"  is to recognize when you're retesting values you've already tested, which would show that you're caught in a loop where all the numbers in that loop are unhappy. Build up a dictionary from there and use it to recognize other unhappy numbers more quickly. I believe that for this formula that's actually practical; for some, it might not be.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `isHappy()` method; I think recursion is the most elegant solution, but a list is needed to prevent entering a loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> checked = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // used to tell if a number has already been checked
public boolean isHappy(int i) {
    if(i == 1)
        return true;
    for(int j : checked)
        if(i == j)
            return false
    int nextNum = ...; // generate the next number (sum the squared digits of i)
    checked.add(nextNum);
    return isHappy(nextNum);
}
```

Hope this helps!